# How might the account 'Flags' evolve over time?

Tags: accounts, flags

From the 'Accounts' section of the docs:

> ### Flags
>
> Currently there are three flags, used by issuers of assets.
>
> #### Authorization required (0x1):
>
> Requires the issuing account to give other accounts permission before they can hold the issuing account’s credit.
>
> #### Authorization revocable (0x2):
>
> Allows the issuing account to revoke its credit held by other accounts.
>
> #### Authorization immutable (0x4):
>
> If this is set then none of the authorization flags can be set and the account can never be deleted.

In what ways do you see this evolving over time (if at all)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some devs have been proposing to add 'Delayed payments' options to secure accounts against hackers, so people could create 'vaults' that can not send out payments if they have the 'delay' flag on paired with a 'delay-days' for n days to wait for payments once the flag has been removed. The flag itself gets removed n days after setting it off to avoid hackers changing the setting and emptying the account.

So ultra paranoid guys like me would set up three kinds of accounts, vaults with 7 days delay for our stash, savings with 2 days for payroll deposits and cash with instant payments for daily purchases funded from savings once a week. That would be an optimal scenario and that would stop hacks like blackwallet and more to come.

Another interesting flag would be the 'Minimum payment allowed' flag that would stop spammers in their tracks if they try to abuse the memo field, so people would set it to their confortable zone like 1 XLM and everything below that mark will get rejected and sent to the inflation pool.

Stellar devs should take notice and the whole crypto world should implement them.

Comment: Vaults can be implemented already using a time lock, which is a combination of  timebounds and pre-signed transactions.